Manually Deriving the OLS Estimators (by hand)
I am trying to derive the three OLS (Ordinary Least Squares) estimators as a learning exercise.
$$ Y = X\beta + \epsilon $$
Where:

$Y$ is an $n×1$ vector
$X$ is an $n×k$ matrix
$β$ is a $k×1$ vector
$ε$ is an $n×1$ vector.

Estimator 1: $\beta$ Parameters
The OLS method minimizes the sum of squared residuals:
$$ S(\beta) = (Y - X\beta)'(Y - X\beta) $$
$$ S(\beta) = Y'Y - Y'X\beta - \beta'X'Y + \beta'X'X\beta $$
$$ \frac{\partial S(\beta)}{\partial \beta} = -2X'Y + 2X'X\beta = 0 $$
$$ X'X\beta = X'Y $$
$$ \hat{\beta} = (X'X)^{-1}X'Y $$
Estimator 2:  Variance of the $\beta$ Parameters
To derive the variance of β-hat,  substitute the true model into our estimator:
$$ \hat{\beta} = (X'X)^{-1}X'Y = (X'X)^{-1}X'(X\beta + \epsilon) $$
$$ = (X'X)^{-1}X'X\beta + (X'X)^{-1}X'\epsilon $$
$$ = \beta + (X'X)^{-1}X'\epsilon $$
Now, we can express β-hat as its difference with respect to the true estimator:
$$ \hat{\beta} - \beta = (X'X)^{-1}X'\epsilon $$
The variance of β-hat is the variance of this random component:
$$ Var(\hat{\beta}) = Var((X'X)^{-1}X'\epsilon) $$
Using the properties of transposes and variances, and the fact that $(X'X)^{-1}X'$ is non-random:
$$ Var(\hat{\beta}) = (X'X)^{-1}X'Var(\epsilon)X(X'X)^{-1} $$
We assume that $Var(\epsilon) = \sigma^2I$ (i.e. homoscedastic), where $I$ is the $n×n$ identity matrix. Substituting this:
$$ Var(\hat{\beta}) = (X'X)^{-1}X'\sigma^2IX(X'X)^{-1} $$
$$ = \sigma^2(X'X)^{-1}X'X(X'X)^{-1} $$
$$ = \sigma^2(X'X)^{-1} $$
Estimator 3:  Overall Variance
Deriving the overall variance was the most difficult and I really struggled with this.
Start with the original model and write the sum of squared residuals:
$$ e = Y - X\hat{\beta} $$
$$ e'e = (Y - X\hat{\beta})'(Y - X\hat{\beta}) $$
$$ e'e = Y'Y - Y'X\hat{\beta} - \hat{\beta}'X'Y + \hat{\beta}'X'X\hat{\beta} $$
Earlier we found that $\hat{\beta} = (X'X)^{-1}X'Y$. Substitute this in:
$$ e'e = Y'Y - Y'X(X'X)^{-1}X'Y - Y'X(X'X)^{-1}X'Y + Y'X(X'X)^{-1}X'X(X'X)^{-1}X'Y $$
$$ e'e = Y'Y - Y'X(X'X)^{-1}X'Y $$
$$ e'e = Y'[I - X(X'X)^{-1}X']Y $$
This part was a bit tricky for me to understand since it seemed arbitrary (and involves projection geometry which I didn't fully understand) - but  we define a matrix $M = I - X(X'X)^{-1}X'$. Then:
$$ e'e = Y'MY $$
Substitute $M$:
$$ e'e = (X\beta + \epsilon)'M(X\beta + \epsilon) $$
$$ e'e = \beta'X'MX\beta + \beta'X'M\epsilon + \epsilon'MX\beta + \epsilon'M\epsilon $$
$M$ is chosen in such a way such that $MX = 0$ and $X'M = 0$  (note 1,2). Using the properties of a Matrix Trace (note 3,4,5,6) this allows us to continue:
$$ e'e = \beta'X'MX\beta + \beta'X'M\epsilon + \epsilon'MX\beta + \epsilon'M\epsilon $$
$$ e'e = 0 + 0 + 0 + \epsilon'M\epsilon $$
$$ e'e = \epsilon'M\epsilon $$
$$ E(e'e) = E(\epsilon'M\epsilon) $$
$$ E(e'e) = E[tr(\epsilon'M\epsilon)] = E[tr(M\epsilon\epsilon')] = tr(ME(\epsilon\epsilon')) $$
$$ E(e'e) = tr(ME[\epsilon\epsilon']) $$
Since $E(\epsilon\epsilon') = \sigma^2I$ and the Trace of a $n \cdot n$ Identity matrix equals $n$ (i.e. sum the diagonal ... $n$ elements all equal to 1) (note 7):
$$ E(e'e) = \sigma^2tr(M) $$
$$ tr(M) = tr(I - X(X'X)^{-1}X') = n - tr(X(X'X)^{-1}X') = n - tr((X'X)^{-1}X'X) = n - k $$
$$ E(e'e) = \sigma^2(n - k) $$
$$ \hat{\sigma}^2 = \frac{e'e}{n - k} $$
This is the final answer. It seems to me that first the overall variance is estimated, then the $\beta$ parameters are estimated, and finally the variance of the $\beta$ parameters are estimated (in that order).
Conclusion: Can someone please help me understand if my algebra is correct?
Much thanks
Footnotes:

Note 1: $MX = 0$.

$$ M = I - X(X'X)^{-1}X' $$
$$ MX = [I - X(X'X)^{-1}X']X $$
$$ MX = IX - X(X'X)^{-1}X'X $$
$$ MX = X - X(X'X)^{-1}X'X $$
Looking at $(X'X)^{-1}X'X $, we can see that:
$$ (X'X)^{-1}X'X = I_k $$
Substituting this back:
$$ MX = X - XI_k $$
$$ MX = X - X $$
$$ MX = 0 $$

Note 2: Dimension of $M$

$X': X' \text{ is } k \times n \text{ (transpose of } X) $

$X'X: (k \times n) \times (n \times k) = k \times k $

$(X'X)^{-1}: (X'X)^{-1} \text{ is also } k \times k $

$X(X'X)^{-1}: (n \times k) \times (k \times k) = n \times k $

$X(X'X)^{-1}X': (n \times k) \times (k \times n) = n \times n $




Thus:
$$ M = I - X(X'X)^{-1}X' $$
$$ (n \times n) - (n \times n) = n \times n $$

Note 3: For any matrices A, B where AB is square:

$$ tr(AB) = tr(BA) $$
Applying this to our problem, i.e. $\epsilon'M\epsilon$:
$$ tr(\epsilon'M\epsilon) = tr(M\epsilon\epsilon') $$

Note 4: The linearity of expectation tells us that for any matrix $A$ and matrix $X$:

$$ E[tr(AX)] = tr(AE[X]) $$
Applying this to our equation:
$$ E[tr(M\epsilon\epsilon')] = tr(ME[\epsilon\epsilon']) $$

Note 5: $\epsilon'M\epsilon$ is a scalar (1x1 matrix).

$\epsilon$ is an $n \times 1$ vector
$M$ is an $n \times n$ matrix
$\epsilon'$ is a $1 \times n$ vector (transpose of $\epsilon$)



Thus:
$$ (\epsilon'M)\epsilon $$
$$ (1 \times n) \times (n \times n) = (1 \times n) $$
$$ (1 \times n) \times (n \times 1) = (1 \times 1) $$
Additionally, we can see:
$$ \epsilon'M\epsilon = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n \epsilon_i M_{ij} \epsilon_j $$
$$ \epsilon'M\epsilon = [\epsilon_1 \cdots \epsilon_n] \begin{bmatrix} 
M_{11} & \cdots & M_{1n} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
M_{n1} & \cdots & M_{nn}
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 
\epsilon_1 \\
\vdots \\
\epsilon_n
\end{bmatrix} $$

Note 6: For any scalar $a$, $a = tr(a)$. Since $\epsilon'M\epsilon$ is a scalar (1x1 matrix), we can write:

$$ E(e'e) = E[tr(\epsilon'M\epsilon)] $$
For any matrices A and B where AB is square, $tr(AB) = tr(BA)$.
Since $E[tr(X)] = tr(E[X])$ for any random matrix X and for a non-random matrix A, $E[AX] = AE[X]$:
$$ E(e'e) = E[tr(M\epsilon\epsilon')] $$

Note 7: Why $tr((X'X)^{-1}X'X) = k$.

$ X \text{ is } n \times k $
$ X' \text{ is } k \times n $
$ X'X \text{ is } k \times k $
$ (X'X)^{-1} \text{ is also } k \times k $



In:
$$ (X'X)^{-1}X'X = I_k $$
Where $I_k$ is the $k \times k$ identity matrix. This is true i.e., $A^{-1}A = I$.
The identity matrix $I_k$ looks like this:
$$ I_k = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 1
\end{bmatrix} $$
The trace of a matrix is the sum of its diagonal elements. For $I_k$:
$$ tr(I_k) = \sum_{i=1}^k 1 = k $$
Since $(X'X)^{-1}X'X = I_k$, we can conclude:
$$ tr((X'X)^{-1}X'X) = tr(I_k) = k $$

It looks fine to me, but I don't think we need to estimate $\beta$ and $\sigma^2$ in any particular order.
Some minor terminology issues:

I usually call $\sigma^2$ the "error variance". The term "overall variance" seems confusing, which may refer to the variance of $Y$ when $X$ and/or $\beta$ are also random.

I will never say the "variance of a parameter", since a parameter is a constant. I'll say the "variance of an estimator" of certain parameter, where an estimator is always a function of data. Similarly, I'll never say the "true estimator", but we can say the "true parameter".


